# Phalcon | nginx | php5-fpm returning wrong controller

Tags: nginx, controller, phalcon

Been stuck on this issue for a while now, making me lose motivation :(. Trying to stay positive.

I can't hit the correct controller when hitting the endpoint /signup. It returns the indexController instead.

I have scoured various questions on the same topic.

This answer didn't work: [Phalcon and nginx - framework run only indexController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096422/phalcon-and-nginx-framework-run-only-indexcontroller/25097131#25097131)

index.php

```
<?php
try {
    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../application/controllers/',
        '../application/models/'
    ))->register();

    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function(){
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../application/views/');
        return $view;
    });

    $di->set('url', function(){
        $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    });

    $di->set('router', function() {
        $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
        $router->setUriSource('/');
        $router->add(
            'signup',
            array(
                "controller" => "/signup",
                "action" => "index"
            )
        );
        $router->handle();
        return $router;
    });

    if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $pathInfo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    } else {
        $pathInfo = '/';
    }


    //Handle the request
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
    echo $application->handle($pathInfo)->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

nginx config (sites-available)

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  Tikarta-berkshelf;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # if file exists return it right away
    if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
    }

    # otherwise rewrite it
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 last;
    break;
    }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need `$pathInfo` remove this:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $pathInfo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} else {
    $pathInfo = '/';
}
```

And update `$application->handle()`:

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

Phalcon knows what to do without you specifying this. You also have a typo in your routing configuration, this:

```
$router->add(
    'signup',
    array(
        "controller" => "/signup",
        "action" => "index"
    )
);
```

Must be this (slash in the wrong place):

```
$router->add(
    '/signup',
    array(
        "controller" => "signup",
        "action" => "index"
    )
);
```

If this doesn't help you'll need to further eliminate the problem. If you nginx config is correct, you should always have $_GET['_url'] value of your request url. If it's not set, try updating the nginx config using the official documentation example and don't forget to restart it to try.