# Phalcon and Nginx - download php file instead execute when in first level

Tags: php, nginx, download, phalcon, slash

I have problem with Nginx and Phalcon configuration.

This is my server block:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name testapp.dev;
    root        /srv/http/testapp/public;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    charset     utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;    
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

It's from Phalcon website: https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/nginx.html

Everything is ok until I don't enter into browser address like this (when there is "Test" module): `testapp.dev/test`. But it works when I pass `testapp.dev/test/` or `testapp.dev/test/part` or `testapp/test/part/`.

Interesting is, that if I enter name of module that don't exist, for example: `testapp.dev/test2`, it executes index file and shows error that module definition path doesn't exist.

To summary above:

- `testapp.dev/test` - not working
- `testapp.dev/test/` - working
- `testapp.dev/test/part` - working
- `testapp.dev/test/part/` - working
- `testapp.dev/test2` - module not exist, but index is executing, so, it's working
- `testapp.dev/test2/` - like above...

When I enter into: `testapp.dev/index.php?url_=/test` it's working.

First thought - I should try add / at the end of `try_files` directive, but when I insert it, it's not working either.

I tried also this:
[Phalcon and nginx - framework run only indexController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096422/phalcon-and-nginx-framework-run-only-indexcontroller). It's like above...

Also I was trying to add trailing slash like this: https://serverfault.com/questions/645667/php-file-downloaded-instead-of-executed-with-nginx-try-files, but no success.

Comment: Have you tried `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;` ?

Comment: yes, sorry that I posted without it, but like I said, I was trying many methods :)

Comment: You're referencing an old documentation link, have you tried following https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/webserver-setup#nginx

Comment: WOW! Now, that's interesting... when I paste server block from new doc, it's working, but when I change port from 8000 to 80 it's not... - i mean, same situation

Comment: Same situation in this server block that I posted - when I change from 80 to 8000 it's working... how and why?

Comment: But... also when I pass `testapp.dev:80/test` it's working..., without passing port it's not...

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache - difference between with and without `:80` might be cache related.

Comment: Heh... it must be browser cache... on other browser it's working... sorry for problem and thanks for help...